# How to prevent entering procedure date earlier than admission

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a form in which i have four date boxes. Arrival date and time and Procedure date and time. How to prevent entering date/time into procedure that is earlier than Arrival?

Comment: By writing some code :-) Seriously though, it will be a lot easier for you to get help here if you show first what you tried, and how it failed.

Comment: I didn't try anything. Just have to figure out how to create a trigger that pops up message and prevents from entering into admission field date that is earlier than procedure.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in the `AfterUpdate` event or perhaps even in the table. Each Field has validation rules that can be written and they always run and will stop bad data.

What have you already tried?